# flask_jwt_extended is throwing an error decoding my JWT. How can I capture it?

Tags: python-3.x, jwt, flask-restful, flask-jwt-extended

I'm having issues trying to capture a malformed JWT error in my app.

I'm using flask_jwt_extended and when I send a manually created JWT. I get this error message:

```
Error on request:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/desmondlim/.virtualenvs/rest-api/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jwt/api_jws.py", line 180, in _load
    signing_input, crypto_segment = jwt.rsplit(b'.', 1)
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/desmondlim/.virtualenvs/rest-api/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_restful/__init__.py", line 266, in error_router
    return self.handle_error(e)
  File "/Users/desmondlim/.virtualenvs/rest-api/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1813, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/Users/desmondlim/.virtualenvs/rest-api/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1799, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/Users/desmondlim/.virtualenvs/rest-api/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_restful/__init__.py", line 458, in wrapper
    resp = resource(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/desmondlim/.virtualenvs/rest-api/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/views.py", line 88, in view
    return self.dispatch_request(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/desmondlim/.virtualenvs/rest-api/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_restful/__init__.py", line 573, in dispatch_request
    resp = meth(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/desmondlim/.virtualenvs/rest-api/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_jwt_extended/view_decorators.py", line 103, in wrapper
    verify_jwt_in_request()
  File "/Users/desmondlim/.virtualenvs/rest-api/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_jwt_extended/view_decorators.py", line 32, in verify_jwt_in_request
    jwt_data = _decode_jwt_from_request(request_type='access')
  File "/Users/desmondlim/.virtualenvs/rest-api/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_jwt_extended/view_decorators.py", line 267, in _decode_jwt_from_request
    decoded_token = decode_token(encoded_token, csrf_token)
  File "/Users/desmondlim/.virtualenvs/rest-api/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_jwt_extended/utils.py", line 80, in decode_token
    encoded_token, verify=False, algorithms=config.algorithm
  File "/Users/desmondlim/.virtualenvs/rest-api/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jwt/api_jwt.py", line 84, in decode
    payload, _, _, _ = self._load(jwt)
  File "/Users/desmondlim/.virtualenvs/rest-api/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jwt/api_jws.py", line 183, in _load
    raise DecodeError('Not enough segments')
jwt.exceptions.DecodeError: Not enough segments

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/desmondlim/.virtualenvs/rest-api/lib/python3.7/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 302, in run_wsgi
    execute(self.server.app)
  File "/Users/desmondlim/.virtualenvs/rest-api/lib/python3.7/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 290, in execute
    application_iter = app(environ, start_response)
  File "/Users/desmondlim/.virtualenvs/rest-api/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2309, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/Users/desmondlim/.virtualenvs/rest-api/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2295, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "/Users/desmondlim/.virtualenvs/rest-api/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_restful/__init__.py", line 269, in error_router
    return original_handler(e)
  File "/Users/desmondlim/.virtualenvs/rest-api/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1741, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/Users/desmondlim/.virtualenvs/rest-api/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 34, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/Users/desmondlim/.virtualenvs/rest-api/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2292, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/Users/desmondlim/.virtualenvs/rest-api/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1815, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/Users/desmondlim/.virtualenvs/rest-api/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_restful/__init__.py", line 269, in error_router
    return original_handler(e)
  File "/Users/desmondlim/.virtualenvs/rest-api/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1719, in handle_user_exception
    return handler(e)
TypeError: invalid_token() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
```

My token is just this

> AUTH_T wrong-token

Which should fail.

I've created a project with the same error:

app.py

```
import resource as testing

from flask import Flask, jsonify
from flask_restful import Api
from flask_jwt_extended import JWTManager

from jwt import InvalidSignatureError


app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['JWT_SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret-key'
app.config['JWT_HEADER_TYPE'] = 'AUTH_T'
app.config['JWT_BLACKLIST_ENABLED'] = True
app.config['JWT_BLACKLIST_TOKEN_CHECKS'] = ['access', 'refresh']
app.config['PROPAGATE_EXCEPTIONS'] = True
app.config['DEBUG'] = False


api = Api(app)
jwt = JWTManager(app)


@jwt.invalid_token_loader
def invalid_token():
    return jsonify({
        'message': 'Invalid token.',
        'error': 'invalid_token'
    }), 401


@jwt.revoked_token_loader
def revoked_token():
    return jsonify({
        'message': 'Token is revoked.',
        'error': 'revoked_token'
    }), 401


@app.errorhandler(InvalidSignatureError)
def invalid_signature():
    return jsonify({
        'message': 'Invalid signature token.',
        'error': 'wrong_token'
    }), 401


api.add_resource(testing.Testing, '/test')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(port=5000, debug=False)
```

resource.py

```
from flask_jwt_extended import jwt_required
from flask_restful import Resource


class Testing(Resource):

    @jwt_required
    def get(self):
        return {'message': 'okay'}, 200
```

This is very odd. From what I've read, what I've done should have solved the problem but it seems that the issue is still around. Anyone have any ideas on a fix? If anyone runs this does it work?

Desmond

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of version 3.21.0 of Flask-JWT-Extended, this will just work without having to make a custom decorator.

Answer (score 6):

Answering my own question so that I don't loose this knowledge and to help any new comers.

It seems that Flask-JWT-Extended doesn't handle the malformed tokens for their @jwt_required and @jwt_refresh_token_required decorators, so we have to write our own.

These are my codes for the decorators:

```
def jwt_needed(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def decorator(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            verify_jwt_in_request()
        except (ValueError, DecodeError, TypeError, WrongTokenError):
            return {'error': 'access token error'}, 401

        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return decorator

def jwt_refresh_token_needed(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def decorator(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            verify_jwt_refresh_token_in_request()
        except (ValueError, DecodeError, TypeError, WrongTokenError):
            return {'error': 'refresh token error'}, 401

        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return decorator
```

These 2 decorators handles the malformed token error (ValueError, DecodeError, TypeError) and also the WrongTokenError (which means that you are passing an access token when a refresh token is required). verify_jwt_refresh_token_in_request is a function of Flask-JWT-Extended itself.

Further to this. If you need admin access to a function, you can also create a decorator like this:

```
def admin_needed(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def decorator(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            verify_jwt_in_request()
        except (ValueError, DecodeError, TypeError, WrongTokenError):
            return {'error': 'access token error'}, 401

        claims = get_jwt_claims()
        if claims['auth'] == 'ADMIN':
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        else:
            return {'error': 'admin required'}, 401

    return decorator
```

This allows for checking of the token and the checking of the claims, all in 1 step.

Hope this would help someone.

Comment: Author of flask-jwt-extended here. Glad you got something in place to fix this up! The value error being raised on a malformed token sounds like a bug in my extension. I created https://github.com/vimalloc/flask-jwt-extended/issues/246 to get that fixed up.

Comment: Cool. Thanks @vimalloc